# device token passing empty to server

Tags: php, objective-c

I'm trying to pass the device token to my server but facing some issues in that everything works in my database its storing as empty I don’t where I'm doing wrong here.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
   { 
       const char* data = [deviceToken bytes];
       NSMutableString * token = [NSMutableString string];

       for (int i = 0; i < [deviceToken length]; i++) {
            [token appendFormat:@"%02.2hhX", data[i]];
       }

       NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/pushnofiy/insert.php?token=%@",token];

       NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
       NSLog(@"token %@",urlString);
       NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
       NSLog(@"request %@ ",urlRequest);

       NSData *urlData;
       NSURLResponse *response;
       urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:nil];
    }
```

If I print the `urlString` its showing the device token but I don't know why its not inserting in the database.

**Code**

```
<?php

    mysql_connect(localhost,$username);
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to find Database");*/
    include "db.php";

    $token =$_GET["token"];

    $query = "INSERT INTO notifi (token) VALUES('$token')";

    mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error("error"));
    mysql_close();
 ?>
```

I don't know what is going wrong in my pls anyone tell where I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. Here is a good [tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ) for PDO. Also, your code is subjected to SQL Injection attack, as you directly allow GET values to be inserted in your query.

Comment: Storing empty string OR no record is inserted ? Your PHP codes have syntax errors, i.e. it cannot be run.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor pls tell me where im doing wrong it will really help full

Comment: before we can help, tell me whether a new record is inserted successfully into database, and more importantly, start learning PHP from basics (avoid w3schools).

Comment: @ShivanRaptor i fully checked my php code its working f9 i think from my xcode itself its passing empty pls tell how resolve that

Comment: it's working? remove `*/` first, then replace all deprecated functions (can you tell is there any record being inserted to DB?)

Comment: @ShivanRaptor in db its storing in empty

Comment: what is the output of `NSLog(@"token %@",urlString);` ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor for urlString im getting the device token but if i print the urlData its showing null

Comment: Why don't you use Async request instead of synchronous one? Use the answer's code.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor i have already used that code also for that also its storing as empty in database if u dont mind can i get ur mail id or skype id so i can share many things

Comment: No, Stack Overflow doesn't work this way. Did you check your GET request in browser?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor ya i checked bro im getting the request correctly

Comment: Last question: Are you sure you use `localhost`? Neither simulator / real device can reach this URL. Use IP instead (something like 192.168.1.1)

Comment: @ShivanRaptor im using localhost but im not using simulator im using the real device

Comment: How can device connect to localhost ? As said, change the URL.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor ok just wait i will check in my online server

Comment: @ShivanRaptor but we passing the value form xcode y we need to run in online we already got the device in xcode using that we can easily store in my localhost itself

Comment: Can you read my comments carefully? **Use IP**. localhost means the device itself. Your PHP does not store in your iPhone

Answer (score 0):

it's better to add error recovery mechanism (if the request fails you will lose your token) and use asynchronous request (send token in background)

**In your AppDelegate.m:**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    NSString * token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", deviceToken];
    //Format token as you need:
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:token forKey:@"apnsToken"]; //save token to resend it if request fails
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"apnsTokenSentSuccessfully"]; // set flag for request status
    [DataUpdater sendUserToken]; //send token
}
```

To send token create new class (or use one of existing): 
**DataUpdater.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DataUpdater : NSObject     
+ (void)sendUserToken;
@end
```

**DataUpdater.m**

```
#import "DataUpdater.h"

@implementation DataUpdater

+ (void)sendUserToken {
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"apnsTokenSentSuccessfully"]) {
        NSLog(@"apnsTokenSentSuccessfully already");
        return;
    }

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myhost.com/filecreate.php?token=%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"apnsToken"]]]; //set here your URL

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error == nil) {
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"apnsTokenSentSuccessfully"];
             NSLog(@"Token is being sent successfully");
             //you can check server response here if you need
         }
     }];
}

@end
```

Then you can call [DataUpdater sendUserToken]; in your controllers when internet connection appears, or periodically, or in **-(void)viewDidLoad or -(void)viewWillAppear** methods

My advises: 
1) I use AFNetworking to send async request and check server JSON response 
2) Some times it's better to use services such as Parse to work with push notifications

Comment: @user3349668 U WORK THIS ABOVE CODE ??

Comment: ya same code only i have used buts not working for me